# New partition destroyed bootcamp bootup

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp, refit

I was happily using bootcamp on my mac to run Windows 7. I then decided to create a shared exFAT partition on the drive as well to share files between the systems. After I did this, windows won't boot anymore ("no bootable device - insert boot disk and press a key").

Searching around, refit seems to be a program that can fix it. However I have wrecked computers before messing with MBR tables and the like, so if anyone can confirm the method of repairing this or validating this input I would appreciate it.

It seems you can fix the problem by using refit. When booting, I select the partition tool. It prompts me with this:

[image]

Does this look correct? I'm kinda worried about it not showing the NTFS partition at the new MBR table, however the start and end lba's match the NTFS one.

Also, can I uninstall refit after fixing the boot tables?

Added  info

The Mac is the newest model with a single SSD disk. OSx is 10.8 and Windows 7. There's a Mac OSx partition, then a shared exfat partition (130 gb) and a NTFS partition (90 gb)

Update

I tried doing the sync. It ended up not doing much, except removing the previous message, leaving me with a blank screen and a cursor when i try to boot windows. Would a reinstall of the bootcamp windows 7 fix the problem? I wont mind really. I also tried booting from a windows 7 usb disk to try and repair the install, however it was not able to find any valid windows 7 installations.

Comment: The first thing I would do is repair the Windows 7 boot manager.  If your unable to do that then your limited to installing Windows 7 again.

Comment: Yes that was impossible. I've erased everything and about to start over again. It seems there can only be X amount of partitions on a drive, and the data partition exceeds by one. Not sure how this is possible to circumvent, without erasing the recovery partition eg.

Answer (score 0):

***DO NOT*** use `gptsync` (the program whose output you posted) on your disk -- at least not yet!

The critical question is: How did you create your exFAT partition? If you created it using OS X's Disk Utility, you may be able to get it working again by using `gptsync`.

If you created the partition from Windows, ***STOP!!*** Modifying partitions on a dual-boot Windows/OS X system from Windows, using the standard Windows tools, will modify your disk's [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) without modifying your *real* partition definitions in the GUID Partition Table (GPT). If you subsequently use `gptsync` on the disk, the GPT definitions will overwrite the (Windows-modified) hybrid MBR partitions, thus making it impossible for Windows to access whatever partition(s) you modified. If you get this far, this situation can be *very* difficult to fix. If you've done this, your best hope is to write down *on paper* the start and end points, expressed in *sectors,* of every partition on the disk, using both the MBR and the GPT values. You can then sort it through, figure out which ones are accurate, create a new GPT with all the correct values, and then re-create a new hybrid MBR with `gptsync` or [`gdisk`.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) This is obviously rather involved and requires a lot of understanding to do successfully, so if you've used Windows to create your new partition, be prepared to spend some time reading up and learning before you do anything. Begin with the links in this paragraph.

In either case, just to be sure, I recommend you use [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) to verify your disk. Launch it on the disk and type `v`. It will produce a report of any inconsistencies, including any mis-matched hybrid MBR and GPT partitions it finds.

Edit: Oops; I missed your edit on the first read. If you've already run `gptsync`, then `gdisk`'s verification will probably be useless. The rest of what I wrote still applies, but if you used Windows to create your exFAT partition, the simplest solution is to re-install Windows. You'll lose all your user files, of course. If you've got important user files, you could try using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to try to recover the lost partition or [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to try to recover individual files. Please post back with clarification about how you created that new partition for more individualized advice.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I created the exfat partition in os x. The more and more i read about this, it seems to not be possible (having a data partition and a windows bootcamp) due to limitations in the mbr table (4 primary discs maximum, osx already uses 3).
I deleted all partitions and did a reinstall of windows (not a problem, i only started using bootcamp yesterday) but i would still love to have a shared data partition. So currently i have the osx partition and the bootcamp one.

Comment: You can have a shared-data partition; you need only remove the OS X partitions from the MBR. This is easily done with the right tool, but rEFIt's version of `gptsync` is *not* the right tool. Use `gdisk` for this or [rEFInd's](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) version of `gptsync`. (Note that rEFInd is a fork of rEFIt, the latter having been abandoned close to four years ago.)

Comment: @Rod Smith You said: "You can have a shared-data partition; you need only remove the OS X partitions from the MBR" and mentioned gdisk. I had a look at the gdisk pages and could not figure out how to do it. Could you please post a link to a step by step instructions or write them here?